# Where is there a manual page for Command Line Editing shortcuts?

Tags: linux, command-line, editing, gnu, man

There are times when I would like to respond to an already existing post, [here specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal), because I want to figure out the source that these people are using for the answers. The answers in that post are great, but I would like to know if there is some sort of manual page that I can access on a local Linux OS in order to be able to see these shortcuts (etc.) so that when I am in the middle of nowhere on a horse-carriage (without internet), I am able to continue my development(growth) within the cyber world.

For example, if I want to know about the *ls* command, I type in:

```
$ man ls
```

and the shell pulls up a manual page in regards to the *ls* command.

Simply put, is there a GNU manual inside Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, CentOS, or any Linux OS? If there is, how do I search for this page explaining the [Command Line Shortcuts](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Introduction-and-Notation)?

P.S. I tried navigating through Google and Stack Overflow to figure out these shortcuts - I got the answer here on Stack Overflow, but I want to know the sources (and if they exist on our local Linux systems) of the answers.

Comment: Welcome SU @Reflected8481

Comment: Except very basic shells that rely on the line discipline, a shell itself is responsible for handling command line editing and keyboard shortcuts you're asking about. You tagged `gnu`, mentioned GNU. The GNU shell is Bash. There is already an answer about Bash and Readline it uses. Other shells may or may not use Readline. It's not clear if you were aware of these dependencies. Did you *advertently* mention GNU to limit the scope basically to Bash?

Comment: Forgive me, for I have sinned. I am a noob learning Linux, but I do have some basic understanding. For that matter, yes I am only limited to working with the Bourne Again SHell as of right now - I did not know that the editing of the commands depends on the shell that I am using. I just want to become adept navigating CLI quickly and efficiently when I am typing(learning) these commands. I want to know if it's possible to lookup a manual explaining shortcuts inside of a Linux distro so that when I am on a boat in Antarctica, I can continue learning - some of these shortcuts translate inWindows

Answer (score 1):

The source for many GNU/Linux distros is [ReadLine](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) but you may find [other alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline#Alternative_libraries) elsewhere. Unfortunately, as it's a library for other programs, it doesn't always come with a manpage for end-users (or [very terse](https://manpages.org/readline)), but often a [devs manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html). However, as it's the only one used by Bash, you may find [a section about it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html) when doing `man bash` (then hit `/^READLINE` or better, I think it's the part you might be interested in, `/Commands for Moving` exactly.) If you want to learn the defaults, learn online like [on catonmat](https://catonmat.net/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet) because official materials focus on customisation. You may also try `info bash`: it's the same content as [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look all of this over, forgive me for I have sinned - I am a noob. I have found the Bash reference manual online, thanks to you all. I will use that, and I will check out all of the information you all have shared with me. Thank you very much.

Sincerely,

Comment: You welcome. We all have been a noob, it's essential to keep learning.